# Add values in columns of multiple dataframes if values in another column are same

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Question related to pandas dataframe

df1:

```
id     count
 1       3 
 2       7
 3      11
```

df2:

```
id     count
 3       6 
 4       8
 5       2
```

df3:

```
id     count
 2       1 
 4       3
 6       9
```

Expected output df:

```
id     count
 1       3 
 2       8
 3      17
 4      11
 5       2
 6       9
```

Any help is appreciated &
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby('id', as_index=False).sum()
```